# Android Nexus Lollipop mediaplayer is mediaplaying seeking continuously

Tags: android, audio, media-player, seekbar

We are trying play audio from url (m3u8 file). Media player starts fine no issues. Audio also plays cleanly. Issue starts when do seek in the player. Behavior very strange. it seeks to the proper position then starts playing audio. After while it seeks again like couples seconds (better word is skips some seconds since it jumps to the position directly) and can be observed in the media playback time counter, again plays for a while again jumps some seconds and this continues till end of the media.

We have our custom seek bar which is nothing but a progressbar, and when we do seek the progress bar we send same seek position to media player by calling onseek() method.

Note: Issue Happens only Lollipop nexus devices(tablet and phone).

Strange observation jump happens only if the time counters last position 9
(i.e if mediaplayed 12:29[mm:ss] then will jump to some other random place 12:3X[mm:ss],again mediaplayed 12:39[mm:ss] then will jump to some other random place 12:4X [mm:ss] )

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the outer manifest to the player. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Usually there are two kinds of m3u8 files involved in HLS playback. The outer manifest consists of the list of urls for streaming media at different bitrates. Each url in the outer manifest points to an inner manifest (or bitrate manifest) which consists of a list of segments / chunks for a certain bitrate.

You might be passing the bitrate or inner manifest to the player. What you need to pass is the outer manifest or a url that would provide an outer manifest to the player.

Comment: To be more precise, the player is looking for the codec info from the outer manifest, and that's why you need to pass the outer manifest.

Comment: but same things does not have repro in other devices. N this issue is been fixed by the nexus ppl in later releases.. its going good now